# Referring to 2D barcodes as "QR Code"

Tags: trademark

The term "QR Code" is a registered trademark in the EU (Filing number 000921775 - at least until 2028) and other countries, hold by Denso Wave Incorporated, Japan.

According to their own [FAQ](https://www.qrcode.com/en/faq.html), it is perfectly fine to use QR Code *images*, while they suggest to indicate the trademark for the *term* itself.

So, would I be supposed to indicate a trademark notice if I advertised a commercial product that makes use of QR Codes ; e.g. if I wrote something like "... just scan the QR Code and ..."?

For me it feels like the term has already became "genericized", sine most of the people I know refer to any 2D barcode as "QR Code".

For this case, I actually *mean* (in terms of "telling what it really is") a "QR Code"; so I "have to" use the wordmark to identify what I am talking about (even though I could call it - more general and less precise/ correct - just "2D barcode", e.g.: "... just scan the 2D barcode and ...").

Does the wordmark also cover the "hyphened" variant "QR-Code"?

Comment: "For me it feels like the term has already became "genericized", sine most of the people I know refer to any 2D barcode as "QR Code"" I agree. I think "QR Code" is the next "Xerox."

Comment: Your iPhone has a built-in library that allows the camera to detect and read about 20 different codes. One of these 20 different codes is a "QR code". Barcodes are not QR codes.

Comment: @gnasher729 if enough people start using "QR code" to denote 2D barcodes then that last sentence will become false.  Language is funny that way, and law has only a limited influence on it.

Comment: "would I be supposed to indicate a trademark notice if I advertised a commercial product that makes use of QR Codes": that probably has more to do with the conditions under which trademark notices are useful or required than about the specifics of the trademark you want to use.

Comment: @gnasher729 I said "people I know refer to _any_ 2D barcode as "QR Code" - I am very aware of the fact that there are more 2D barcodes than just the one "QR". But that doesn't add any value to my question TBH.

Comment: @phoog I stated an example how the trademarked term shall be used. Within a sentence that describes an action: "just scan the QR Code". Simple question: is someone required to indicate trademark owner in this case or is there some exception?

Comment: @Chilippso is anyone ever required to indicate the trademark owner for a trademark they don't control?  I don't think so.  Companies frequently do indicate trademarks owned by others because they want to avoid being sued for trademark infringement, but that's typically because of very cautious lawyers rather than any actual requirement.